# remove unused tag library (prize tag) from Eclipse Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee, taglib

I have removed the [Prize Tag](http://www.jenkov.com/prizetags/tabbed-pane-tag/installation.html) .jar and .tld files.
And I think I have removed all the tag lib declaration at the top of the JSP page.
But every time I run the project it keeps spitting out the following message (in red):

```
Apr 12, 2012 3:43:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:www.jenkov.com/projects/prizetags is already defined
Apr 12, 2012 3:43:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:www.jenkov.com/projects/prizetags is already defined
Apr 12, 2012 3:43:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:www.jenkov.com/projects/prizetags is already defined
Apr 12, 2012 3:43:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:www.jenkov.com/projects/prizetags is already defined
Apr 12, 2012 3:43:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:www.jenkov.com/projects/prizetags is already defined
Apr 12, 2012 3:43:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: urn:www.jenkov.com/projects/prizetags is already defined
```

I'm really puzzled, please shed some light on where should I look to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1):

With ctrl+H -> File Search Look for all the files in your workspace containing *prizetags*

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove the tag lib descriptors (.tld files) from the META-INF directory ?
(This is the step 2 of [installation process](http://www.jenkov.com/prizetags/tabbed-pane-tag/installation.html).)